# Is there a SpreadsheetApp.flush() option for the Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that I send data to it, I generate a 1-minute *sleep* (`import time → time.sleep(60)`) in the code to make sure that the calculations have all been done and then I copy the result of these calculations to another page of that same spreadsheet.

In *Google Apps Script* there is the `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` option to make sure that everything in the spreadsheet is perfect to continue the code.

But what about when we use the *Google Sheets API*, is there a way to do this instead of putting a *sleep* with a random value like I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about that too, so I reviewed the documentation, and it seems that there is no [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) method for Sheets API.

However, I found a workaround that might help so you can make sure that you are working on the latest version of the sheet. I took inspiration from the [Writecontrol parameter](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#writecontrol) in Google Docs API.

> "Determines the revision of the document to write to and how the
> request should behave if that revision is not the current revision of
> the document."

So what I was thinking is to use the [Drive API Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/change-overview) by using the [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) method and get the latest version of the Sheet. After that, use [Revision: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get) to retrieve the latest version of the sheet to work on it.

You can also submit a [missing feature](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#missing_features), Google might add this method to the Sheets API later on.

**Reference:**

- [Flush() method.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)
- [Writecontrol Google Docs API.](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate#writecontrol)
- [Changes and revisions overview.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/change-overview)
- [Revisions: list.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- [Revisions: get.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get)

Comment: Hi @GiselleValladares thanks for the informations, if you want to help, I created a feature request, they say that the more "likes" and "favs" the ideas receive, the greater the chance of it attracting attention, so if possible, support the request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237019266

Comment: Cool, I add a "like" to the request too.